# Adding more information to a Content Product Category

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, template-tags, widget-text

The template **content_product_cat** is responsible for showing the product categories images and its name. I want to display more information below the name of a category e.g a Category called 'Books', I want to show 'Find all health related book here' below that category and vice versa

```
<h1>"Books"</h1>
<p>Find all health related book here</p>
```

How can i do that? There is only option for 'Short Description' for products,which can be displayed via

```
`echo apply_filters( 'woocommerce_short_description', $post->post_excerpt );`
```

but i want to show the text for each category.
There is no place to enter a description under WordPress admin for woocommerce plugin.

Comment: I've reopened this as this question can be rephrased to be more generic, aka "How do I attach a piece of text to a taxonomy term and display that text in the archive listing?"

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is not Woocommerce specific, and can be generalised as:

> Given a term in a taxonomy, how do I attach a chunk of text to that term and display it in the term listings?

In this case, the taxonomy is the one provided by Woocommerce.

To do this you need to first get the current term being queried:

```
global $wp_query;
$term = $wp_query->queried_object;
```

Then you need to display some text. I suggest you use the term description:

[image: A screenshot of the term description field in the WordPress admin area]

You would then display this description using the `$term` variable we grabbed earlier:

```
echo $term->description;
```

You may even wish to run `the_content` filter on it so that you can use shortcodes etc:

```
$description = apply_filter( 'the_content', $term->description );
echo $description;
```

Things to be wary of:

- The queried object may not be a term, it may be a date or a post, if that's the case, the above code will fail, so only put this on taxonomy archive templates, not general
- The description field is not a WYSIWYG visual editor. This does not prevent you using it this way, and you could turn it into one, but that is beyond the scope of this question.

Comment: @Tim J Nowell , I know this one. But i don't need thatmPerhaps I will rephrase my question.

Comment: I don't see how you couldn't implement exactly what you want using this, can you elaborate? Why can you not add to the description of the product category?

Comment: If i add description, it doesn't show up on content_product_cat.php page but single-product page, which i don't i want.I want to show description for each category and not product

Comment: I don't understand what you've just said, it's hard to follow. Your question states the template 'archive' for products, ***not*** the `single-product` template, that single product template is irrelevant to your question, and is a separate problem with its own issues.

Comment: I edited my question now, with specific of the template. I am new at woo, so took me a while to find out where is that template.